# Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded],

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My Database was working good one hour before. Every thing Worked finem but I get issues now.

> Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded],

I am checking on path database not copy. I am also checked the target membership of the sqlite file.

```
- (NSString *)getDBPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Boom.sqlite"];
}

- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
        NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Boom.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

**But I get this error:**

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010494b3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001045e4bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010494b25a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010420228f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   BoomAGift                           0x000000010286dce7 -[AppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded] + 663
    5   BoomAGift                           0x000000010286d8c0 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 800
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000102a825a5 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 234
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102a830ec -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2463
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102a85e5c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102a84d22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001059aa2a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104880abc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104876805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048765c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104875a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000102a84799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102a87550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  BoomAGift                           0x000000010289fd53 main + 115
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001053cf145 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: please log the error of success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

Comment: and try with remove the sqlite from the bundle and add again some time it happen because the sqlite file not copied successfully in bundle

Comment: @chiragshah what i can do can i remove my database file

Comment: just remove reference and add it again in your bundle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76519/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-varun).

Comment: they show same error